# Using Mat2cell to split 256 x 256 matrix into 3 x 3 matricies

Tags: matlab

I need to split a 256 x 256 matrix into 3 x 3 matricies and mix of 1 x 3 and 3 x 1. I want to have 85 3 x 3 matricies and the rest are either 1 x 3 or 3 x 1. I have tried this:

`C = mat2cell(in,[3 3 1],[3 1 3]);`

Comment: The code you give will handle a 7x7 matrix and the result will have the last row `1xn` and the middle column `mx1`. Is that where you want the 1-dimensions in the 256x256 case? (`m` and `n` in this case are either 3 or 1, not the sizes of the overall matrix.)

Comment: I want to get 85 3 x 3 matricies and the rest in 1 x 3 and 3 x 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) requires that you put *all* of the rows and *all* of the columns in the distribution vectors:

```
C = mat2cell(in, [ones(1,85)*3, 1], [ones(1,85)*3, 1]);
```

In this case,

- `C{1:85, 1:85}` will all be `3x3` matrices
- `C{86, 1:85}` will all be `1x3` matrices
- `C{1:85, 86}` will all be `3x1`, and
- `C{86, 86}` will be `1x1`